# Mule Session variables are persisted across some but not all transport barriers

Tags: mule, mule-component, mule-esb

I know Session  variables  are  persisted  across  some  but  not  all  transport  barriers for example they  are  not  propagated  across  the  HTTP  transport  barrier. 
Can anyone help me to know what are other transport barriers in mule which does not allow propagation of session variable.

Comment: I also know VM transport barrier allow propagation of session variable.

Answer (score 0):

Session variables set with a session variable transformer persist for the entire message lifecycle, regardless of transport barriers, except for the HTTP Connector which doesn’t propagate them.

Ref below link

[session-variable-transformer-reference](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.9/session-variable-transformer-reference)

Answer (score 0):

Session variables are used when we want to retain the value(s) across transport barrier within the flow. These session variables will not be available in the http request flow API but only within the flow they are declared. They are meant to be use in place of flow variables when there is any transport request in the flow.

Answer (score 0):

To carry values over http you can set outbound property which will be available as inbound property after http barrier.

Below link explains property scope in detail
https://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/anypoint-platform-dev/mule-school-the-mulemessage-property-scopes-and-variables/